# How to formulate a stateful query with Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking to use Google BigQuery for a framework in which I anticipate having to often run stateful queries. By stateful query, I mean that the query uses state that it associates with rows as it runs.

For example, a query that takes the first row of column `X`, for a given order, in which column `xflag` is set to `1` and subtracts it from the first row of column `Y` for which column `yflag` is set to 1.

The way I run these queries is to create intermediate tables. In the example above, to mark "first" rows of both types with a `firstx` or `firsty` flag, and then in two separate queries, to compute their difference. This is quite cumbersome. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider below "one-shot" option

it is for bigquery standard sql

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY IF(xflag = 1, xpos, 9999) LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] -
  ARRAY_AGG(y ORDER BY IF(yflag = 1, ypos, 9999) LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] diff  
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

Note - it assumes that the field that you use to determine `given order` is `xpos` and `ypos`. Also note use of 9999 - in your case this value should be of same type that above mentioned `xpos` and `ypos` and that value must be greater that any possible value of these fields in your table - this makes sure that only xflag = 1 and yflag - 1 rows are accounted

Usually such positional fields are of timestamp type so you can use something like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` for example

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using subqueries, instead of intermediate table,

- SQL [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause) might be good choice, it allows you reference subquery data many times, simplifying your logic, that is based on specific column and row values.
- You may also consider using  [CASE expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions) or 
  [WINDOW function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#window-clause)